# How can I insert InstallDirDlg into a custom dialog sequence?

Tags: wix, installation, customdialog

I construct installer with custom dialogs and want to set action for the `Next` button to go to the directory selection dialog. So I use this code:

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="[ButtonText_Next]">
  <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

But the `InstallDirDlg` dialog is unknown here because I don't include `WixUI_InstallDir` schema.

So can I include it somehow or I should find the `InstallDirDlg` source and copy it to my `.wxs`?

(I try to modify the [samples code](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/system/files/samples/SampleCustomUI.zip) `SampleCustomUI7.wxs` from the [WiX tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/a-single-dialog)).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should refer to documentation, it has exactly this example in chapter "Customizing Built-in WixUI Dialog Sets", based on your "WixUI_InstallDir" UI type:

[Inserting a custom dialog into a built-in dialog set](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html)

Comment: Thanks. But I guess I need something opposite. I'm trying to incorporate `InstallDirDlg` dialog to my code from the `WiX` source but have some problems with the correct `PathEdit` `Property` value. I thought it's possible to add something like `-ext InstallDirDlg` to the `light.exe` parameters. But for now I see I can only set `-ext WixUIExtension` and override `WixUI_InstallDir` set.

Comment: There is no way to include jut one dialog, since it's kind of meant to work together with other things from the UI. If your UI is not based on the standard UI, you could just copy the source file of the dialog you need from WIX and paste it in your project.